# Numdocs appearing as 0 in Solr Admin

Tags: curl, solr, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I've been trying to set up Solr with Cassandra and ran into an issue. I've been following this tutorial: http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchTutCreatTab.html. I know it's outdated but I assumed it would still work as I am on Cassandra  3.10 (maybe this is why I'm running into my issue?). Anyways, I created a new keyspace (`CREATE KEYSPACE stacko WITH REPLICATION ={'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1':1};`) and table (`CREATE TABLE test1 ( name text PRIMARY KEY, address text, age int, solr_query text);`). I then proceeded to add 4 rows to the database successfully.

My schema.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schema name="TestSolrSchema" version="1.5">
<types>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField" name="StrField"/>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TrieIntField" 
name="TrieIntField"/>
</types>
<fields>
<field docValues="true" indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="name" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field docValues="true" indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="address" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field docValues="true" indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="age" stored="true" type="TrieIntField"/>
</fields>
<uniqueKey>name</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

The solrconfig.xml looks like how it was when downloaded from Datastax (no changes made to it).

I then proceeded to run these lines: 
$ cd into/directory

$ curl http://localhost:8983/solr/resource/stacko.test1/solrconfig.xml --data-binary @solrconfig.xml -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'

$ curl http://localhost:8983/solr/resource/stacko.test1/schema.xml --data-binary @schema.xml -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'

$ curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=stacko.test1"

However, when I open the Solr Admin portal and go to my Core Admin page, I see this:

[image: Image of Solr Admin]

I cannot perform any queries as there is no data to query apparently... Any reason as to why this may be happening? I haven't been able to figure it out. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: what version of DSE are you using? In 5.x you can use `dsetool` to upload files, reindex, etc.  In 5.1 you can also do it from `cqlsh`

Comment: Hmm realized I never downloaded DSE and that it isn't free...lol

Comment: It's free. For development ;-)

Comment: True, downloading now :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to tell DSE to reindex the content into Solr, look up the [doc](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchReldCore.html) for details, but typically would be something like this:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&name=stacko.test1&reindex=true&deleteAll=true"
```